# Unity Mirror Enemy Spawned, but sprite not showing

Tags: unity, mirror-networking

I am using Mirror's Scene Interest Management. I am creating a server only then in another instance joining as client. My player loads into the scene and then the enemy spawner begins to spawn enemies. I see the enemies on the server screen, but the enemy sprites do not show up on the client screen. The enemies are there on the client, they can even hit the player and cause damage, but they are invisible.

Any ideas about what might be causing this?

Comment: So it looks like the enemy is rotated and invisible due to its rotation. It's a 2d game. Not sure whats setting this rotation. Do enemies need network transform ?

Comment: The Network Transform component synchronizes the position, rotation, and scale of networked game objects across the network. It depends on your game if you need it or not. Not every time the position on the server has to match the position on the client.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: that is, every step a reader would need to follow to reproduce this problem, starting from a new, empty project..Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test potential solutions to make sure they'll work for you.